# How to create upstream tarball from Git repository of Debian package

Tags: debian, git, packaging

I have a Git repository with these branches:

```
debian
master
pristine-tar
upstream
```

I do *not* have an upstream tar ball. Can I create an upstream tarball from the Git repository I have? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`pristine-tar`](https://manpages.debian.org/pristine-tar/pristine-tar.1) to reconstruct the tarball.

List the available tarballs with

```
pristine-tar list
```

then reconstruct the tarball you want with

```
pristine-tar checkout foo.tar.gz
```

(replacing `foo.tar.gz` as appropriate).